# Alternate cut off matrix

Tags: analytics, sas-jmp

[image]

If I have an alternate confusion matrix similar to one above. I am trying to predict bad risk.
I do understand that with .04 probability I am able to find more bad risk but I would want to know what implication does this .04 has interms of business.Why do I want a different cut off then .5?